# netbeans unable to connect through proxy

Tags: netbeans

I am using Netbeans 7.1.2 IDE on Ubuntu.  I have to connect to the outside world through a proxy that requires authentication.

So, for updating new plugins to my Netbeans, I have given the proxy settings including authentication details in the "advanced proxy settings" dialog.

Tried various combinations of user name like:

```
<username>
<domain>\<username>
<domain>\\<username>
```

Inspite of this, nothing works and Netbeans complains that it is unable to connect. Whereas I am able to connect to internet for regular browsing using the proxy.

Is this a defect in Netbeans which is still unaddressed?  I saw some defects raised (more than 2 years ago) in the netbeans bugzilla, which are either closed or not simulatable.

Am I missing something here?